# Translating {{ model.name }} data dynamically in django template

Tags: django, django-models, internationalization

Can anyone suggest shortest way to translate {{ model.name }} type of data in django template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Templates aren't supposed to do buisiness logic` in django,
in a good way you need to pass already translated data in your template.

Although if you actually in need to do it, you can use `django filters`:

[Link to django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.filter)

Code may look like this:

`new_filter.py`

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def translator_filter(string_to_translate):
    translated_string = #do logic with translation here
    return translated_string
```

`any_page.html`

```
<p>{{ model.name|translator_filter }}</p>
```